# Mocking a method inside class in python test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to Python and writing a unit test for the already existing code.

I have the following Python code structure:

```
root_project:
-- src 
   -- signUp 
      -- __init__.py 
      -- abc.py 
      -- xyz.py
```

**abc.py** contains the following code:

```
from . import xyz
class Abc: 

      def __init__(self):
         pass 
      
      def start_process(self):
         xyz.start_timer()
```

I want to mock `xyz.start_timer()` inside method `start_process` of class Abc so that `start_timer()` mock version can be used.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This would be much easier if you inverted the dependency - if `xyz` was a parameter to the `__init__` of `Abc` rather than an import, you could trivially inject a test double when instantiating `Abc` in the tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply patch the `start_timer` function using [mock.patch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch).

**abc.py**

```
import xyz

class Abc: 

      def __init__(self):
         pass 
      
      def start_process(self):
         xyz.start_timer()
```

**test_abc.py**

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase

from abc import Abc

class Test_Abc(TestCase):

    @mock.patch("abc.start_timer")
    def test_start_process(self, mock_start_timer):
        # your test code
```

Notice that I have patched `abc.start_timer` and not `xyz.start_timer`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to patch`xyz.start_timer()`, I just added `return` to `start_process` to show that the patching really does what it should:

```
import xyz
import unittest
from unittest import mock


class Abc:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start_process(self):
        return xyz.start_timer()


class Test_Abc(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('xyz.start_timer', return_value=True)
    def test_start_process(self, start_process):
        a = Abc()
        self.assertTrue(a.start_process())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Out:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```